# How to get the content in the mouse floating window?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

the content of the floating window is not included in the web code. it only appears when the mouse is over it. So how can I obtain the value in this situation? I find it tricky cuz there's no anchor point for me to control the movement of the mouse.

The code is like below,

```
def button_click(driver, button_num):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_num)


def catogory_obtain_tokyo(driver):
    time_waiting_max = 20
    try:
        page_kansai = WebDriverWait(driver, time_waiting_max).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'snippet-13'))
        )

        buttons = WebDriverWait(page_kansai, time_waiting_max).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mv-button-base.mv-hyperlink-button"))
        )
        return buttons
    except:
        print('catogory_obtain error')
        driver.quit()
        return ''

path = r'chromedriver.exe'
tokyo_url = r'https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures#%7B%22snippetpicker%22%3A%22EEX%20Japanese%20Power%20Futures%20-%20Tokyo%22%7D'

# --- time line ---
timeline = '//*[@id="null"]/div/div[2]/div'

# ------- price trade reg ----
pane_pr = '//*[@id="null"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]'

# --------volume trade registration ------
pane_vtr = '//*[@id="null"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(tokyo_url)

btns = catogory_obtain_tokyo(driver)
button_click(driver, btns[0])

time.sleep(3)

# sep-03 btn
date = '//*[@id="symbolheader_jft"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]'
date_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, date))
)
time.sleep(5)
date_btn.click()

# hit icon
icon_path = '//*[@id="baseloadwidget_jft"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]'
icon = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, icon_path))
)

time.sleep(5)
icon.click()

time.sleep(5)

# --------- click volume btn ------
vtr_path = '//*[@id="baseloadwidget_jft"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]'
vtr_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, vtr_path))
)
time.sleep(5)
vtr_btn.click()

time.sleep(5)

tl = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, timeline)
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(tl).perform()
time.sleep(5)

pr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, pane_pr)
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(pr).perform()
time.sleep(5)

vtr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, pane_vtr)
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(vtr).perform()
time.sleep(5)

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Basically, I tried the `move_to_element` method, but it only moves the mouse to the center of element. However, here this inline chart is considered as one element, how can I control the movement of the mouse within one single web element?

Comment: Do you mean actions performed by mouse hovering?

Comment: @fam yes, something like this. but how can I get the relative position between my mouse and the data table? Actually, I want the mouse to move inside the element.

Comment: Please provide the current code example and the website you are trying your method on.

Comment: This is the [website](https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures#%7B%22snippetpicker%22%3A%22EEX%20Japanese%20Power%20Futures%20-%20Tokyo%22%7D). Pls check the data on 2021-09-03 in `week` category named `week 36/21`, click the icon at the end of the line and u can see the line chart. this is the table where I want to crawl data from.

Comment: @Leo_Liu - What is expected output?

Comment: @pmadhu - Just like the floating window beside the mouse would be fine. Date plus the value number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is answer you are looking for.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures#%7B%22snippetpicker%22%3A%22EEX%20Japanese%20Power%20Futures%20-%20Tokyo%22%7D")
time.sleep(30) # Manually selected the options.
blocks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mv-panes-host']/div[3]/div[2]//*[local-name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][2]//*[name()='rect']")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
for block in blocks:
    actions.move_to_element(block).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='null']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[contains(@class,'date')]").text)
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='null']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div//div[contains(@class,'name')]").text)
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='null']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div//div[contains(@class,'value')]").text)


driver.quit()
```

```
9/3/2021, 01:53:23 PM
Volume Trade Registration
840.000
9/3/2021, 01:56:26 PM
Volume Trade Registration
840.000
```

Comment: May I ask why u write the xpath this way `//div[@class='mv-panes-host']/div[3]/div[2]//*[local-name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][2]//*[name()='rect']` ? I use the xpath `//*[@id="null"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/svg/g[2]/g/g/*`  and it is not working.

Comment: @Leo_Liu -Because we are trying to find an element which is an `svg` tag. If you observe in the DOM, element for `//*[@id="null"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]` will be detected  but `/svg` wont. To find the element in `svg` tags we need provide xpath something like this `//*[name()="svg"]` or `[local-name()='svg']`